# I have an error duplicate layout for login page

Tags: next.js

I have an error duplicate layout for login page, please help me fix it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWV7c.png)This is my directory structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8skhk.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq0Da.png)

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Next.js',
  description: 'Generated by Next.js'
};

export default function LoginLayout ({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
    <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
    </div>
    {children}
    </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
import Navigation from '@/app/components/navigation.js';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Next.js',
  description: 'Generated by Next.js'
};

export default function RootLayout ({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
    <body>
    <Navigation />
    {children}
    </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.